# Header in CSS that goes across the page

Tags: css, header

So I've tried padding changes and width 100%. I've been looking for week or so trying to figure this out. I want the header image to go across the page and my footer. My footer works but header doesn't..Here is my CSS code:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body{

    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;

}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,span
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}


#headerbg
{

width:100%;
height:360px;
float: left;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
background-image:url(images/headerbg.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat-x;



 }

 #headerblank
{
    width:1004px;
    height:309px;
    float: none;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0px;
}
 #header
{

width:100%;
height:360px;
float: left;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
background-image:url(images/header.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;

}
```

Thanks for your help and suggestions!

Comment: Can you include the relevant html? What is #headerBlank?

Comment: Yes #headerBlank seems odd, it has a set width as well, try making that 100%

Comment: website is [link](http://saltmediaandproductions.com)...HTML..Honestly #headerBlank not sure what it function is..grab this code to start from.

Comment: #headerBlank making it 100% didn't work..thank you tho

Comment: Your problem *is* the width on #headerBlank. I removed it and immediately the header was full width (excluding the browser's default padding/margin on body).

Comment: I removed it and no change??

Comment: Also remove the fixed size from header. (By remove, I mean, change it to 100% instead.)

Comment: So here it is changed but I still see no change.#headerbg
 {
 
 width:100%;
 height:360px;
 float: left;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 background-image:url(images/headerbg.jpg);
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 
  

       }
  
     #headerblank
 {
  width:100%;
  height:309px;
  float: none;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0px;
 }
    #header
 {
 
 width:100%;
 height:360px;
 float: left;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 background-image:url(images/header.jpg);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 
 }

Comment: I am visiting your site with Firefox and Firebug (an amazing add-on, in case you aren't familiar with it). If I remove the height from #headerBlank and change #header's width to 100% (with Firebug), it seems to me to do what you have asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 #header
{    
   width:1004px;
   height:360px;
   /*float: left;  remove this */
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   padding:0px;
   background-image:url(images/header.jpg);
   background-repeat:no-repeat;

}

#headerBlank
{
   width:100%;
   /* the rest of your css... */
}
```

Tested this on the website link you gave on Chrome.